# C# framework 2.0 Return two value from method

Tags: c#, methods, return

i create a dll with C# framework 2.0 and want use that in another applications...
but i have a problem
i cannot return two value from method
for example:

```
        public string Two_String_Returner()
    {
        int aa = 50;
        string bb = "Hello";
        return aa.ToString();
        return bb;
    }
```

1-i must return two value, once is int and another is string
2- this return should be Apart from each other

i how can do this?

Comment: You could return a structure or a class. You can return a Tuple or use ref or out params. Or you could use google..

Comment: if is possible give me a example return two value code please

Comment: The thing is: YOU CAN'T. But you can either return a complex 'package' with 2 (or more) values inside or use `ref` or `out` parameters. Do get yourself a tutorial, a book or use google. SO is not the right place for this kind of question!

Comment: Yes,i before ask question tryed to solve that but i did not success and ask for help، for example I tested the Tuple but that return multiple value in one return,i want return the value in apart of each and pop returns whit nsis

Comment: I do not know what _pop returns whit nsis_ might mean but the truth is: You can't always get what you want, even if you think you know what it is.

Answer (score -2):

You can return an array of strings.

```
public string[] Two_String_Returner()
{
    int aa = 50;
    string bb = "Hello";
    return new string[] { aa.ToString() ,  bb};
}
```

Comment: when i tryed this, i see the retrun value "System.String[]"

Comment: The OP specifically said they want to "return two value, once is int and another is string" - this returns an array containing two strings.

Comment: She *says* `once is int and another is string` but then converts the int to string in the return statement